# CSS3 transform an element but not its descendants

Tags: css, menu

I have an horizontal menu and I want to rotate 90° left or right some of its tabs.
Problem is that the transform property also rotates descendants.
It looks difficult to put them back in place, is there a solution?

P.S. I want to avoid using images or JS, they are ok as fallbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the reverse rotation on the descendants.

For example

```
div.parent{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
}


div.parent span{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RpcfB/1/

Fyi, you will need to play with `padding` and/or `margin` to make it all work.

**EDIT**

> I'm afraid it's more complicated than that.

That's the truth!!  Although, I as mentioned, you have to play with the css.

For example, to fix the first one, you need to make these adjustments:

1. add a class to the first `li`

   ```
    #nav_main_gts > li.rotate{ //ADD CLASS HERE
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=-1);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
   ```
2. Then change the second rule to target the next `ul` not `li`
3. Then fiddle with the `margin` to get it all in place.  Remember, because the first `li` is rotated, down is not left, so a negative `margin-left` is needed

   ```
    #nav_main_gts > li.rotate ul{ //CHANGE TO UL HERE
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
       transform: rotate(90deg);
       margin-left:-100px;  //ADD A MARGIN HERE
    }
   ```
4. continue with the others.

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FKCTk/1/

Comment: I'm afraid it's more complicated than that. I tried applying a counter rotation to descendants but each li is positioned wrong in relation to each others. Further more the counter rotation on level 2 must itself be countered for level 3 and that's the pain in the ass that I want to avoid. Here's my code, to see what I mean click on "C Level 1" > "Level 2" so that Level 3 appears http://jsfiddle.net/elddifsj/FKCTk/

Comment: I tend to get lost when I have to select the proper element. I think I have it working: I didn't add a class and for Level 3 I used `#nav_main_gts > li > ul ul{-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}` 0deg, weird, and like you point out down becomes left, a real nightmare. So your method works, thanks. P.S. I was told that it's possible to rotate only the parent element with the folowing selector but I failed, any clue ? `ul#nav_main_gts > li > a{}`

Comment: I know.  I get lost too!  Glad you got it all worked out.  Not sure about that last rule... doesn't look right to me.

Comment: About `#nav_main_gts > li > a{}`, I got the trick: by selecting <a> we prevent the declaration to apply to descendants because… <a> has no descendants ! while li and ul do. In my case it is the preferred method as it doesn't rotates sub menus and I just have to reposition the main ones.

Comment: Awesome @user2534!  Glad you sorted it out.