# CSS Custom shape twitter bootstrap button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, shapes

Spent 2 hours already, trying to get it work, but so far I only get this:

```
.btn-custom{ width:100%; border-bottom: 100px solid blue; border-left:80px solid transparent; }

.btn2 {
display: inline-block;
padding: 4px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);

}
```

and this would be the button itself:

```
<a href="#" style="height:145px;line-height:80px;font-size:18px;" class="btn2 btn-block btn-custom">test</a>
```

What I'm trying to make is this:

[image]

I think I would also need the transform:rotate function to rotate the button, but is there a way to rotate it, without rotating the text?

At the moment, with the code I've posted above the button isn't looking the way it should look, it's a bit shorter (height), the text is not where it should be and if I rotate it, the text rotates too. That is what it looks like now:

[image]

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you create a relative positioned CSS shape with an absolute positioned text div on top?

`<div id="shape"><div id="text">hi</div></div>`

Comment: How would you position the text above shape in a bootstrap responsive theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use css shapes? Check out the demo I put together ([**result**](http://cdpn.io/odCzF) and [**snippet**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/odCzF)) it might help you.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your response, yes I do want to use css shapes. Your code is almost exactly what I'm trying to do, beside, if I use transform:rotate(180deg); it turns the text too. I would like to have one "button" with a sliced off right bottom side and another with right top side, as in the image I've posted.

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514200/css3-transform-an-element-but-not-its-descendants

it is a small hack but seems to be working. And if you want to slice the top, just change the border-bottom property to top.

Comment: Do you see any possibility to use this css hack with solid transparent instead of white (or any other color for the actual corner)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using that image as background for that particular div.

Comment: I don't want to use images, it is supposed to be a responsive website, that's how I found out about css shapes, but then I thought it would be cool to transform the bootstrap buttons a bit as it's based on the twitter bootstrap, the site is split in 3 span4 within span12